# Mesh/Shading Issue in Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, shaders

I'm not too sure what is going on here to be honest.

I had seperated the part of the mesh where the cockpit windows are, but when I joined it back up together, It shows me a weird shading that I can't get rid off.

I've tried removing doubles, and recalculating normals.

Any suggestions?

Look forward to hearing,

Karl.[image]

Comment: have you tried a W > Shade Smooth? Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Yes, in that picture, it's shaded smooth.

Comment: please share your file or at least a part of it, it's hard to tell what's your problem without the file

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6602" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6602/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have faces that don't stick together, you can fix this with an <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance*, and play with the distance parameter in the last operation box (bottom left of the 3D view).

[image]

You'll still have artefacts where the triangles are very stretched, you should better use quads, but if you are lazy you can cut your triangles with additional edge loops (use the knife tool) and it will improve the shading.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help!